# Where in the SSMS UI can I see the user's execute stored procedure permissions?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

For a particular database user, I want to see the user's execute permissions on the stored procedures in the database. For example: Whether he can execute all stored procedures or only certain stored procedures.

Where in the SSMS UI can I see the user's execute stored procedure permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the details using below steps

1. Right click the database user
2. Go to properties
3. Navigate to Securables tab/page

under securables you can find the object for which the user has access. by selecting an object you can see the permission details as shown in the image below.

[image]